# Printing an object parsed with Aeson does nothing

Tags: haskell, websocket, aeson

Relatively new to Haskell and cannot understand why the following is not working.

I am parsing an object out of a websocket query using Aeson and trying to print it.

All prints before the one in question work, but this one never prints. I also tried variants with `fromMaybe` and providing a default value, but that didn't help either.

Command is just a record object holding several (Maybe Map)s of various objects. All of them have FromJSON instances, etc.

Normally just one of the maps is present, but I intend to perform some accumulation later on, which may mean several objects were passed at once.

```
data Command = Command { _articles :: Maybe ArticleMapMaybe
                       , _clients :: Maybe ClientMapMaybe
                       , _orders :: Maybe OrderMapMaybe } deriving (Show, Eq, Generic)

instance FromJSON Command
instance ToJSON Command


-- take a request from the queue and service it
wsApplication :: MVar ServerState
              -> WS.ServerApp
wsApplication state pending = do
  putStrLn "Processing request"
  let path = WS.requestPath (WS.pendingRequest pending)
  putStrLn $ "path: " ++ (BS.unpack $ BS.fromStrict path)

  conn <- WS.acceptRequest pending
  query <- WS.receiveData conn
  putStrLn $ "query: " ++ (T.unpack query)

  let command = (A.decode $ BS.pack . T.unpack $ query) :: Maybe Command
  print command -- this doesn't do anything!

  let client = (query, conn) :: SocketClient
  modifyMVar_ state $ return . addClient client

  serverState <- readMVar state
  putStrLn $ "connected clients: " ++ (show . length $ serverState ^. connectedClients)
  perform state client command
```

Result:

```
Processing request
path: /api
query: {"_clients":null,"_orders":null,"_articles":{"dsa141":{"_notes":"ewq","_articleName":"Stellaris: Apocalypse"}}}
Processing request
path: /api
```

If I remove the "print command" line, the following lines are also printed ("connected clients"). This implies that when printing the command the function blocks..? Obviously the result of the parsing doesn't depend on any MVars or anything of the sort (and "connected clients" does print, meaning the server state MVar is not blocked...).

Comment: Just to discard issues with unflushed output buffers, what happens if you put a `hFlush stdout` after every `putStrLn` / `print` ?

Comment: Does `A.decode :: ByteString -> Maybe Command` work properly in ghci? Possibly related: `BS.pack . T.unpack` ought to be a crime. Figure out how to just receive bytes without attempting to decode them then re-encode them (probably in a different encoding) first. Anyway I guess what I'm getting at is this question needs an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @danidiaz thanks I tried this before, but to no avail.
@DanielWagner thanks I just realized there is `cabal new-repl`! Will try it now. And yes, btw it is possible to receive the data as `ByteString` from the WebSocket with no conversion, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So, I tried decoding the json in ghci, and I get `*Server A BS> print $ (A.eitherDecode $ BS.pack queryString :: Either String ArticleMapMaybe)
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse` So the result is an error message "no parse". I found that I don't get this message if I remove the initial `_` from the json keys... maybe this is not allowed by json standard? So now I have to change my record fields and see if that works... or alternatively write manual to/fromJSON instances.

Comment: Update: turned out the Aeson parsing was failing, but in such a way that eitherDecode wasn't returning a left... perhaps it was crashing? The problem was with a From/ToJSON instance I had hand-written for Data.Decimal. Changed it now and everything seems to be working.